Send Excel Data from VBA to C# for Real-Time WPF Binding
I have a simple question:
How can I, from a VBA script, send the current instance of my workbook to a C# application?
The idea behind this is to read the Excel data and enable real-time data binding with a WPF interface.
Best regards,
CM

To little information. Where is the real-time client? Why do you need to run the VBA script?

The main goal is to create a WPF GUI to assist users in completing an Excel workbook with around 200 columns. Ideally, I would like the GUI to update the worksheet in real time, and vice versa. What you mean by real-time client ?

Ok, it seems it's not related to Real-time computing. The only method for the .NET app to communicate with the open Excel workbook is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Refer to How to access Office interop objects.

The only method for the .NET app to communicate with the open Excel workbook is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelProgrammingWalkthruComplete {
    class Walkthrough
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a list of accounts.
            var bankAccounts = new List<Account>
            {
                new Account {
                              ID = 345678,
                              Balance = 541.27
                            },
                new Account {
                              ID = 1230221,
                              Balance = -127.44
                            }
            };

            // Display the list in an Excel spreadsheet.
            DisplayInExcel(bankAccounts);
        }

        static void DisplayInExcel(IEnumerable<Account> accounts)
        {
            var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            // Make the object visible.
            excelApp.Visible = true;

            // We need to communicate with the active workbook.
            Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

            // Earlier versions of C# require explicit casting.
            //Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;

            // Establish column headings in cells A1 and B1.
            workSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "ID Number";
            workSheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "Current Balance";

            var row = 1;
            foreach (var acct in accounts)
            {
                row++;
                workSheet.Cells[row, "A"] = acct.ID;
                workSheet.Cells[row, "B"] = acct.Balance;
            }

            workSheet.Columns[1].AutoFit();
            workSheet.Columns[2].AutoFit();

            // Call to AutoFormat in Visual C#. This statement replaces the
            // two calls to AutoFit.
            workSheet.Range["A1", "B3"].AutoFormat(
                Excel.XlRangeAutoFormat.xlRangeAutoFormatClassic2);

            // Put the spreadsheet contents on the clipboard. The Copy method has one
            // optional parameter for specifying a destination. Because no argument
            // is sent, the destination is the Clipboard.
            workSheet.Range["A1:B3"].Copy();
        }
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public double Balance { get; set; }
    }
}

It allows to interactively work in both Excel and your WPF app simultaneously and exchange data dynamically in both directions.
